# Discrete Math - Prove function is onto with two variables

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, formal-proofs

Let :  →  , : →  be total functions.
We define:
ℎ:  ×  →  ×  by ℎ(, ) = ((), ())

Prove: ℎ is onto iff ,  are onto

The logic is clear, if h is onto, (), () has to be able to generate every value in C and D, hence f and g are onto as well. And vice versa.
But I have no idea on how to write it formally and rigorously...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying $h$ is onto is equivalent to saying that for each $(c,d)\in C\times D$, there is at least one $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $h(a,b)=(c,d)$. But this is equivalent to saying that there is $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $f(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$, which itself is equivalent to saying $f$ and $g$ are onto.

It is probably simpler to work direct and reciprocal implications separately.